# Как открыть модальное окно Bootstrap без JQuery и bootstrap.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

В моем проекте не используется JQuery и bootstrap.js, так уж сложилось. Стараемся как можно меньше использовать библиотеки.

Нужно реализовать модальное окно, но использовать вышеупомянутые JQuery и bootstrap.js ради одного окошка - крайне не желательно.

Есть ли решение этой проблемы?

Comment: > Как открыть модальное окно Bootstrap без JQuery и bootstrap.js? Вырезать из bootstrap.js нужный функционал. А вообще чем плохо подключить все как положено и не изобретать велосипед?

Comment: http://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/#exampleModal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например самое простое с применением псевдокласса `:target`:

```css
/* Стили для модального*/
#modal {
  display: none;
}

/* Изменяем вид вывода при соответствии */
#modal:target {
  display: block;
}

/* Закрытие модального*/
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}


/* Доп. стилизация модального*/
#modal {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}


/* Стилизация кнопки, чтобы глаз радовала.*/
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #111;
  background: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#modal" class="btn">вызвать модальное</a>
  
  <div id="modal">
    <a href="#close" class="close">x</a>
    <h3>Модальное окно</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, quidem!
  </div>
```

> Псевдо класс :target является одной из замечательных особенностей
>   CSS3. Он соответствует элементу, на который указывает идентификатор в
>   URI документа.
>
> Идентификатор в URI содержит символ “#”, за которым следует имя
>   идентификатора, соответствующее значению атрибута id элемента в
>   документе.

Comment: Какое отношение имеет стилизация кнопки к открытию модального окна?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Насколько понимаю, стилизация – для красоты :) А суть решения – [псевдокласс `:target`](https://webref.ru/css/target).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky и это тоже бы следовало объяснить...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Согласен. Будет правильно добавить пояснение в начало ответа и/или перенести класс для кнопки в конец кода стилей.

Comment: Мне нужно объяснять почему я стилизовала кнопку?! Вы это серьезно?!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko Достаточно пояснить, что вы делаете. В ответе первым шёл большой кусок про красивую кнопку. И пояснений никаких не было.  Поэтому вопрос Павла мне кажется и естественным, и полезным для дела.